# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Remove footer in output file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm using `SQL Server SSMS` to output a query to a space delimited text file.  It works fine with one exception.  At the bottom of the file it prints a message about how many lines it printed just like when the query is routed to the results grid in `SSMS`:

```
  id         sales       region
 001          100,000       North
 001          100,000       North
 001          100,000       North
 001          100,000       North
 001          100,000       North
 ...             ...         ...


(78482 row(s) affected)
```

This is a problem as there are multiple files and they are read into another program where this message causes an error.

I've looked around in the output and query options but don't see any way to fix this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`set nocount on`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx) in the beginning of the query/inputfile.

> Stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected
>   by a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure from being returned as
>   part of the result set.